# CSS :hover effect is not working in my code

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>
    <title> 
        test
    </title>
    <head>
        <style>
            .header {
                position: absolute;
                font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                color:bisque;
                top:100px;
                left:300px;
            }

            body {
                position: absolute;
                background-image: url(pexels2.jpg);
                height: 50%;
                width: 50%;
                background-size: cover;
            }

            .container1 {
                position: absolute;
                height: 330px;
                width: 330px;
                left: 100px;
                top: 250px;
                background-size: contain;
                transition: 2s;
            }
            .container1:hover {
                transform: scaleY(-20px);       
            }
    
           
        </style>            
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container1">
            <img src="pexels-pick2.jpg" width="330px" height="330px">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

i think the box should go up when i hover on it but it doesnt

Comment: ScaleY() works with relative values try for example scaleY(1.2)

Comment: By "go up" I assume you mean move vertically? If so you want a `translate` not a `scale`.

Comment: Try transform: translateY(-20px); and read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale

Comment: scale is for resizing, what is your goal here ?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
    <title> 
        test
    </title>
    <head>
        <style>
            .header {
                position: absolute;
                font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                color:bisque;
                top:100px;
                left:300px;
            }

            body {
                position: absolute;
                background-image: url(pexels2.jpg);
                height: 50%;
                width: 50%;
                background-size: cover;
            }

            .container1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 330px;
    width: 330px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 250px;
    background-size: contain;
    transition: transform 0.5s; /* Apply transition to transform property only */
}

.container1:hover {
    transform: translateY(-100px); /* Move the box 100px up on hover */
}
    
           
        </style>            
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container1">
            <img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/purple-white-and-orange-light-tZCrFpSNiIQ" width="330px" height="330px">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Changes Made: scaleY(-20px); to transform: translateY(-20px); in the .container1:hover class: In your provided code, transform: scaleY(-20px); was used to scale the element along the Y-axis, which would make it appear smaller. However, to move the element up or down, the translateY() function of the transform property is used. So, I changed it to transform: translateY(-20px); to move the element 20 pixels up along the Y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code. It works for bringing the image up.

```
.container1:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2); /* Scale up by 20% on hover */
}
```

Comment: This increases the size, it does not move the element up.

Comment: Bringing up .....like bringing up as a stack ,that's what it does.